React Native Android app created with Expo crashes when I open the map component
I'm developing an expo application, and I'm using MapView in there to render a map, but I'm using react-native-map-clustering that wraps the react-native-maps. When I open the app through the expo, it works perfectly, but when I build the app and install in my android emulator, every time I try to open the map, the app crashes and close immediately.
Here is my component:
     <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION}
        showsUserLocation
        showsMyLocationButton
        minZoom={2}
        maxZoom={20}
        clusterColor={COLORS.secondary}
        onRegionChangeComplete={async (region, markers) => {
          if(calculateRadius(region) > placesMapShow.raio){
            setPlacesMapShow({
              raio: Math.min(calculateRadius(region)/2, 10),
              latitude: region.latitude,
              longitude: region.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta,
            });
            await refetch();
          }
        }}
      >

My android session of my app.json file:
"android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ccc"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
      ],
      "package": "com.boucher.app",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "******"
        }
      }
    },

I have read in some places that I had to configure de sha-1 key between Google Play developers and Google Cloud to ensure that the maps api-key would be connected, but I didn't found where and how to do it, and thought that put the apiKey in app.json, and then set the PROVIDER_GOOGLE as a map provider could be enough.
I tried the following approaches:

Put the maps api key in android.config.googleMaps.apiKey in app.json and PROVIDER_GOOGLE as MapView property;
Made de recomendations from MapView expo page, like get the sha-1 id and upt as restriction for API Key in Google Cloud.


Hi Have you registered app on google console and also enabled map api ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started#create-project

Hello, @Joedson Santos, could you please give the exact error log that shows me the type of issue you're having throughout the installation process? Alternatively, you can use cli or terminal to enable logcat, which displays the emulator logs.

Hi Vidhi Dave! I found that the problem was exactly with the api key. On google console it was configured as android map sdk, but for any reason the app was still crashing, and after building and rebuild cleaning all of the caches in expo, the map is finally working on the release version.

After a lot of debgging, I found that the problem was ocurring due to environment variables access. All of the values were undefined, and I believe that apiKey was inaccessible as well. For the googleApi key I had to check if the android manifest was receiving the google apiKey here:
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="API_KEY"/>

And for the rest of the values, I found that importing env directly on custom hooks was not working, so I started to import the variables in React Native components, and passing as arguments for the fetch functions in the hook modules. From React components I was able to import everything from environment.
